# acro package in pandoc with \tableofcontents throws error (LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined")

Tags: acronyms, pandoc, acro

UPDATE (MWE):

Tracked the error down independently from the template. Apparently it occurs as soon as I try to add a table of contents:

`preamble.tex`contains:

```
\usepackage{acro}
```

`test_acro.md` contains:

```
\tableofcontents

\DeclareAcronym{api}{
  short = API,
  long = Application Programming Interface,
}

\printacronyms

\ac{api} is an abbreviation.
```

running

```
pandoc test_acro.md -o test_acro.pdf -H preamble.tex
```

throws

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \g__acro_api_in_list_bool already defined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.66 }
```

---

**ignore from here**

Sorry for not having a minimal working example, but I'm rather trying to get a hint what's going wrong than a readymade solution.

I'm using https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown as a template for pandoc.

My makefile has been altered by me to use some additional filters (pandoc-shortcaption and pandoc-crossref).

After having included

```
\usepackage{acro}}
```

in the style/template.tex

and for testing

```
\DeclareAcronym{api}{
  short = API,
  long = Application Programming Interface,
  class = abbreviation
}

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbreviation, name=Abbreviations, 
heading=chapter, sort=false]

\ac{api} ist eine Abkuerzung.
```

in source/*abbreviations.md, I get:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \g__acro_api_in_list_bool already defined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.279 }

pandoc: Error producing PDF
pandoc.log (END)
```

Any idea what's going on here? I've read about people using the acro package with pandoc without problems.

Comment: This `phd_thesis_markdown` is quite a huge project.  Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which reproduces you problem

Comment: That's exactly my problem. If I could see where the error comes from I'd be already one step further.

Comment: You track it down, we solve it.  That's the deal here.  Nobody is going to waste their time on this.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for wasting your time on clarifying this. See above for the MWE I've found in the meantime. Any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing your code fragment

```
\tableofcontents

\DeclareAcronym{api}{
  short = API,
  long = Application Programming Interface,
}

\printacronyms

\ac{api} is an abbreviation.
```

Into a *real* MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\DeclareAcronym{api}{
  short = API,
  long = Application Programming Interface,
}

\printacronyms

\ac{api} is an abbreviation.
\end{document}
```

produces the error and shows the problem: the declaration of the acronyms should be made in the preamble!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{api}{
  short = API,
  long = Application Programming Interface,
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\printacronyms

\ac{api} is an abbreviation.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The question is about `pandoc` generated LaTeX, but the problem is similar I guess.

Comment: It's a working example, even if it's not minimal because still using pandoc and it's templates. That I couldn't see that it has nothing to do with pandoc was obviously part of my problem. So from my perspective it was an MWE. Thanks anyway, solved the problem!

Comment: @HenriMenke In the end it must be the same document however the LaTeX code is generated, no? There surely must be a separation of preamble and document…

Comment: @clemens Yes, it is the same problem. I've edited my filename for the preamble in my question to make this answer easier to understand and apply for other pandoc users.